Is there any way to make sphinx tell me which .rst file caused an error or make it ignore the file that is failing?
I'm trying to convert a big project's documentation to plaintext.
"make html" works fine, but "make text" throws an error:
sphinx-sitemap: No pages generated for sitemap.xml. 

Sphinx parallel build error:  
NotImplementedError: Nested tables are not supported.  

I'm not sure if the first line is part of the error but just in case I'm including it.
Problem is, I have no way to actually fix this! The program doesn't tell me which file is causing the issue (and I have thousands of them), I don't see an option to just skip the file and continue converting the rest either.
What are my options? Bisecting the database will be a nightmare.

This SO question might provide a clue. Also the error message is in the Sphinx text writer, as you have probably realized, so if you search your docs' source for table or other markup for tables, then you may find the offending nested table.
